# How to build a 64 bit application on 32 bit OS? [c#]

Tags: c#, .net

I have a application which implements Geckofx web browser control. I have 64 bit compiled geckofx.dlls(compiled from a 64 bit OS). But currently i don't have access to 64 bit OS and i want to compile the whole application with the 64bit geckofx.dlls targetting 64 bit OS. How can i do that from my 32 bit OS?

I need a good tutorial to do this. Do i need to download and install 64 bit compilers in my pc? if so, how? and how to check if i already have that compilers?

Comment: [How to: Configure Projects to Target Platforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185328.aspx)

Comment: @Alex Visual Studio is 32bit.  I'm pretty sure you can... To expand a little, you don't have to be _running_ on a target architecture to _compile_ for it.  For instance, when working with my arduino, my intel chip does the compilation.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Did you encounter a problem? Have you tried simply changing the build target? You don't need to install any additional x64 compilers, they are installed by Visual Studio itself

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I recall this was not the case on C++ (at least on old Visual Studios, I haven't done C++ for eons) and you indeed needed to install the 64 bit compilers. Defeinitely not the case for .net AFAIK

Comment: @Jcl actually, it's pretty hard to find a 32-bit version OS version to test this nowadays - any machine with 4 GB or more is x64.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed, I don't think I've used a 32-bit OS since Vista came out (XP64 was horrible though)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think I've ever done this, but can't you just set the code generation ("platform target") as `x64` in the project's "Build" configuration?

Or, in the command line: `csc.exe /platform:x64`?

As far as I know, the C# compiler (`csc`) is a 32bit application, it should be able to generate code for any supported platform

Comment: That is correct. VS has no trouble targeting either 64bit or 32bit code. The code simply won't run in a 32-bit OS

Comment: Hi Guys. The problem here is the geckofx.dlls are already compiled from a 64 bit OS  to run in 64 bit platform. So i think its the reason causing the crash of my application. I did tried building the application using 64bit geckofx dll targetting 64 bit platform. But its always crashing when i run it in 64 bit OS. But i can make it run if i compile the whole application from a 64 bit OS. So I don't know why can't i compile it from my 32 bit OS. (Note: I am getting warning:mismatch of processor architecture and dlls)

Comment: Compiling and running are two different things

Comment: @JamesThorpe No, there are no errors in the application. I can get the same application running without any problems if compiled from 64 bit OS.

Comment: @Nisthar what is the exact runtime error when you run the app compiled in your 32 bit system, in a 64 bit system? Have you tried debugging that exe in the 64 bit system? You can run VS like this: `devenv /debugexe <path to exe>` in your 64 bit system, to catch any exceptions during startup.

Comment: @Fede It crashes without showing an error. The usual not responding do you want to close or debug window appears.

Comment: @Nisthar then debug it and see what happens. But let's get something straight: if the very same project, compiled with the very same options, and with the very same libraries, crashes when compiled with one OS but works when compiled with another (running the resulting executable in the same OS), there's something else provoking it, not related to the compiler settings. The resulting .exe (and/or .dll's) *should* be exactly the same no matter if you compile it under a 32-bit OS or a 64-bit OS. If it's not: then there is something else going on, and we can't guess it.

Comment: @Nisthar where you able to debug it with `devenv /debugexe`? By any chance, are you doing `ngen` as a step in your build process? If the project that builds the exe targets `AnyCPU` or `x64` it should run as a 64-bit process on 64 bit systems.

Comment: @Fede If the project is using native 64bit DLLs I'd advise against `AnyCPU` and target `x64` directly, so that it doesn't even try to run on a 32-bit Windows (it should throw the `blablabla.exe is not a valid Win 32 application` if trying to run it on a 32 bit OS).

Comment: @Jcl I agree with you. Just wanted to point out that by default C# projects are `AnyCPU`, so by default it should work, although it's extremely dangerous, as you pointed out, if running in a 32 bit system it'll throw something like a `BadImageFormatException` instead of giving a more appropriate error message.